# ID dinámicos con jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html5, phpmyadmin

La idea principal de este ejercicio es crear un sistema que se pueda utilizar en un restaurante donde se pueda seleccionar una mesa y se pueda agregar los productos que desee estoy trabajando con PHP, Mysql, Jquery intento de llenar el td de la tabla que tienen id dinámicos que funcionan de la siguiente forma:

```
function agrega_fila(){
var td = 0;
var qty = 0;
var producto = 0;
var peso = 0;
var precio = 0;
 function agrega_fila(){
    qty ++;
    td ++;
    producto ++;
    peso ++;
    precio ++;
    fila = ' <tr id="fila'+td+'" ><td class="col-xs-3" ><div id="qty'+qty+'"></div></td><td class="col-xs-3" id="producto'+producto+'"></td><td class="col-xs-3"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">Kg</div><input id="peso'+peso+'" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div></td><td class="col-xs-3"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="precio'+precio+'" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div></td></tr>';
    $("#fila").before(fila);
 }
```

luego con ajax solicite los datos del producto seleccionado y retorna con un json

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
//Carga los productos al formulario

$("#selec-prod button").click(function(){
          id_prod = $(this).val();
          id_mesa = $("#btn-mesas option:selected").val();
         if(id_mesa == null){

            alert("Es necesario que seleccione una mesa");
         }else{
                 $.ajax({
                 type:"GET",
                 url:"lib/pedidos/select_producto.php",
                 data:{id_prod:id_prod,id_mesa:id_mesa},
                 dataType:"json",
                 success: function(data){
                        var cant = prompt("Ingresar Cantidad:");
                        if(cant>0){

                            $('#qty).text(cant);//llenado de las filas 
                            $('#producto').text(data.DESC);
                            $('#precio').val(data.PRECIO);
                            agrega_fila();// se agrega una fila  adicional 

                        }else{
                            alert ("La cantidad debe ser mayor a 0");
                        }
                 },error:function(res){
                        alert("[AJAX] Error: capturando el arreglo!! ");     
                 }
            });
         }

 });

});
```

Mi duda es ¿Cómo puedo llenar la entrada de datos dinámicos en esta parte de mi código? sonda con siguiente pero no me funciono

```
var qty =0;
qty ++;

$('#qty'+qty).text(cant);//llenado de las filas 
$('#producto').text(data.DESC);
$('#precio').val(data.PRECIO);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución**

en la primera parte de tu código quita las comillas simples así:

> id="qty+qty+"

**El problema**
`id="qty'+qty+'"` no es igual que `id="qty+qty+"`

Esta parte de tu código:

```
function agrega_fila(){
var td = 0;
var qty = 0;
var producto = 0;
var peso = 0;
var precio = 0;
 function agrega_fila(){
    qty ++;
    td ++;
    producto ++;
    peso ++;
    precio ++;
    fila = ' <tr id="fila'+td+'" ><td class="col-xs-3" ><div id="qty'+qty+'"></div></td><td class="col-xs-3" id="producto'+producto+'"></td><td class="col-xs-3"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">Kg</div><input id="peso'+peso+'" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div></td><td class="col-xs-3"><div class="input-group"><div class="input-group-addon">$</div><input id="precio'+precio+'" class="form-control input-md"  type="text" value="0"></div></td></tr>';
    $("#fila").before(fila);
 }
```

está generando id que se ven así:

> id="qty'1'"

```
y lo que buscas en el siguiente código:

var qty =0;
qty ++;

$('#qty'+qty).text(cant);//llenado de las filas 
$('#producto').text(data.DESC);
$('#precio').val(data.PRECIO);
```

se ve de esta forma:

> id="qty1"

Comment: Compañero no me funciono su sugerencia sigue llenándome solamente la primera fila... sabes como puedo depurar?

Comment: Tienes esta linea de código: `$('#qty).text(cant)` en ella el selector #qty no llama a nigún elemento porque en primer lugar la comilla simple no la cierras nunca y en segundo lugar, no tiene ningún id, puedes presionar la tecla f12 (usualemte) para ver la consola y ver errores de javacript

Comment: Muchas gracias @Emiliano Pamont funciona quedo  de la siguiente manera `$('#qty'+idqty).text(cant);   idqty ++;` Ahora tratare de sumar los sub-totales

Comment: Si es la respuesta que soluciona tu problema puedes marcarla cómo resuelta